# Mysqli query returning itself instead of results

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

```
<?php

$top10 = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM entries ORDER BY Votes ASC");

if ($top10->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $top10->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<li>" . $row['name'] . " " . "Votes: " . $row['Votes'] . "</li>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
?>
```

Instead of returning each row from the db, this just returning itself starting with query("SELECT ...

Comment: Where's your database connection?

Comment: $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","root","", "contest");

Comment: It connects just fine on my other pages

Comment: *"this just returning itself starting with query("SELECT..."* - I don't know what you mean by that. Do you mean it's showing as code?

Comment: Yes. @Fred-ii- On the page, it is literally returning "query("SELECT * FROM entries ORDER BY Votes ASC");

if ($top10->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $top10->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<li>" . $row['name'] . " " . "Votes: " . $row['Votes'] . "</li>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
?>"

Comment: then this tells me you're running this as `file:///file.php` rather than `http://localhost/file.php` (or `.html`).

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP code is not being executed I can see it on source code of page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121495/php-code-is-not-being-executed-i-can-see-it-on-source-code-of-page)

Comment: @Fred-ii-  Its running on localhost.

Comment: what're you running under, Wamp, mamp, Xampp, other?

Comment: well your system's not parsing the PHP directives. Also, is this a `.php` file or `.html`?

Comment: You do not need to use `ASC` in your query as it is always `ASC`